# Let error in scheme

Tags: lisp, scheme

I have written the following code snippet in scheme,

```
(define (test-for-prime number divisor)
  (cond (prime? number) (number)
        (else (let ((next-divisor) (find-next-divisor number (+ 1 divisor)))
                 (test-for-prime (/ number next-divisor) (next-divisor))))))
```

However, I get the following error

> let: bad syntax (not an identifier and expression for a binding) in: (next-divisor)

How do I rectify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this version, it fixes all the *syntax* errors:

```
(define (test-for-prime number divisor)
  (cond ((prime? number)
         number)        
        (else
         (let ([next-divisor (find-next-divisor number (+ 1 divisor))])
           (test-for-prime (/ number next-divisor) next-divisor)))))
```

You have lots of misplaced parenthesis. Some are missing, some are mistaken ... I'd suggest you take a good read at a Scheme tutorial and play around writing some basic procedures to get the hang of it, in particular [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html) is the documentation and correct structure for a `let` special form:

```
(let ([id val-expr] ...) body ...+)
```

> The first form evaluates the val-exprs left-to-right, creates a new location for each id, and places the values into the locations. It then evaluates the bodys, in which the ids are bound. The last body expression is in tail position with respect to the let form. The ids must be distinct according to bound-identifier=?

Also it's a good idea to use an IDE/editor which highlights this kind of problems and helps you indent the code properly. In particular, be aware that a variable must not be surrounded in parenthesis, when you write this: `(x)` Scheme assumes that `x` is a procedure and that you're calling it.

Answer (score 1):

`Let` has the following syntax (example with two bindings):

```
(let ((<var> <expr>)
      (<var1> <expr1>))
  <body>)
```

If we fill in your `let` form, you have two bindings: `next-divisor` gets bound to nothing, and `find-next-divisor` gets bound to `number`, but there is a third form `(+ 1 divisor)` that does not fit into `let`'s syntax.

This might be what you want:

```
(let ((next-divisor (find-next-divisor number (+ 1 divisor))))
  ;; ...
  )
```